# Number of wavelengths in a multiple node optical fiber topology

Tags: multiplexer, optical-fibre

I'm given a topology with several nodes that works bidirectional, so bit rates must be multiplied x2 (topology is attached at the bottom of the message) and a table with the required bit rates between nodes (which are attached too). Furthermore, it is known that every wavelength in the net carries up to 10 Gbps.

I'm told to calculate the number of wavelengths needed if:

a) we are using transparent nodes (ASON, for instance).

b) we are using opaque nodes (SDH, for instance).

The thing is that I'm not given any mathematical orientation in my notes, just some theoretical approach, so I don't even know how to start dealing with the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the path between the nodes constrained in any way?  For example there are numerous paths between A & E (A-C-E, A-D-E, A-D-C-E, ...).  Do all of these have to be considered?

Comment: Hi, SteveSh! The only restriction is "assuming the shortest way between nodes". Hope it helps! Thanks